# Swift Metal Default library not created

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I'm creating an iOS SDK for a tool I'm developing. Now I am running into problems with Metal.

I have coding experience, but not (yet) a whole lot with Swift/Metal, so I'm struggling :D

So I:

- created a new iOS Framework, added in a metal file called "Shaders.metal"
- Added the Shaders.metal file to my target (can see it in build phases)
- Added in 3 functions vertexMain / fragmentMain / blurFragmentMain (code later)
- Have my main swift Class where i try to initialize my device and MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor
- I set up a test swiftUI project and linked my other Framework to this app. It all works except for the metal part. Maybe something goes wrong there? Do I need to compile it?

Now there it goes wrong, I can't create a defaultLibrary using

```
guard let library = try? metalDevice.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle: frameworkBundle) else {
            fatalError("Failed to create default library")
        }
```

Error I'm getting

```
Error: Error Domain=MTLLibraryErrorDomain Code=6 "no default library was found"
```

Full Code Here:

```
//
//  Shaders.metal
//

#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <SwiftUI/SwiftUI_Metal.h>
using namespace metal;

vertex float4 vertexMain(constant float4* vertices [[buffer(0)]], uint vertex_id [[vertex_id]]) {
    return vertices[vertex_id];
}

fragment half4 fragmentMain() {
    return half4(1.0); // This just returns a white color. We'll replace this later.
}

fragment half4 blurFragmentMain(texture2d<half> inputTexture [[texture(0)]], sampler s [[sampler(0)]], float2 texCoord [[stage_in]]) {
    // Sample multiple pixels around texCoord and average them
    // This is a simplified version; a real blur shader would be more complex
    half4 color = inputTexture.sample(s, texCoord);
    return color;
}
```

```
import Metal
import MetalKit
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire


public class MetalExample {
    private var metalDevice: MTLDevice!
    private var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!
    private var pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState?
    

    public init() {
        if let metalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() {
            self.metalDevice = metalDevice
        }
        
        if metalDevice == nil {
            print("Device is nil!")
        } else {
            print("Device is not nil.")
        }
        
        commandQueue = metalDevice.makeCommandQueue()!
        let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        guard let library = try? metalDevice.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle: frameworkBundle) else {
            fatalError("Failed to create default library")
        }
        
        guard let vertexFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "vertexMain") else {
            fatalError("Failed to load vertex function")
        }
        guard let fragmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "fragmentMain") else {
            fatalError("Failed to load fragment function")
        }

        // Create a pipeline descriptor
        let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
        pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
        
        pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction
        pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction
        
        // Create the pipeline state
        do {
            pipelineState = try metalDevice.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)
        } catch {
            print("Error creating pipeline state: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Podfile of my test app

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'X_Test_App' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'X_iOS_SDK', :path => '../X-ios-sdk'
  # Pods for X_Test_App

end
```

I've been googling and going at it for days, but I can't find it ... Can someone help me out?

Comment: Instead of using `try?` you should use `do/try/catch` and print the error inside `catch`

Comment: @jnpdx error is "Error: Error Domain=MTLLibraryErrorDomain Code=6 "no default library was found""

Comment: Could this be a solution? It says executable, I'm building a framework. https://mtldoc.com/metal/2022/06/18/build-swift-executable-with-metal-library